# Search a worksheet for a cell value, then copy the adjacent cells into a variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I have several Excel workbooks with each workbook containing multiple sheets.

I do a keyword search across all worksheets using a particular value ("James Smith"). If the value is found, then I need to offset five columns over from that cell location (i.e. the "found cell" which will always be in Column C somewhere so the offset is pointing to column H) and then select/copy the adjacent rows into a range that will ultimately be pasted into a new worksheet "masterSheet".

The problems are:

1. The cell address in each of these sheets will vary so that the cell address is not the same in each worksheet
2. I get errors when I try to set the `FoundRange` value below.

```
    'Search multiple workbooks, look only for sheetnames that begin with "Week of" and don't contain the word "old"
    
    If currentSheet.Name Like "*Week of*" And InStr(currentSheet.Name, "Old") = 0 Then
        'If currentSheet.Name Like "*Week of*" Then
                
        'Within the current sheet look for a cell that contains "James Smith"
        With currentSheet
                
            .Range("C:C").Columns.Select
                
            Set FoundCell = Selection.Find(What:="James Smith", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                
            'When "James Smith" is found in the current worksheet, get the cell address and offset from that cell location"
            OffsetCell = currentSheet.Range(FoundCell.Address).Offset(0, 5).Address
    
            'In Column "H" select the adjacent non-blank cells and copy into a range <line below where I define "FoundRange" is where I keep getting the "runtime error 424 object required error"
            Set FoundRange = Range(OffsetCell, OffsetCell.End(xlDown))

            For Each cell In currentSheet.Range(FoundRange)
                If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                    currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Copy
                    masterSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    masterSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Format(CDate(Replace(Replace(currentSheet.Name, "Week of ", " "), ".", "/")), "mm/dd/yyyy")
                    masterSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1) = "James Bradford"
                    currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Copy
                    masterSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Copy
                    masterSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Copy
                    masterSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            Next              
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: `OffsetCell` is a string so `OffsetCell.End(xlDown)` makes no sense, it needs to be a range `set OffsetCell=FoundCell.Offset(0, 5)`. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: You can just do `Set FoundCell = .Range("C:C").Find(...`.

Comment: And `currentSheet.Range(FoundRange)` should just be `FoundRange` as it is already a range. Perhaps do some reading up on ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This works. FYI... You have James Smith in the find and James Bradford in the loop. I added a mastersheet for testing, so get rid of the "Set masterSheet" line.

```
Sub RngTest()
'Search multiple workbooks, look only for sheetnames that begin with "Week of" and don't contain the word "old"

Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet
Set masterSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet")
If currentSheet.Name Like "*Week of*" And InStr(currentSheet.Name, "Old") = 0 Then
    'If currentSheet.Name Like "*Week of*" Then

        'Within the current sheet look for a cell that contains "James Smith"
        With currentSheet

        .Range("C:C").Columns.Select

        Set FoundCell = Selection.Find(What:="James Smith", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        'When "James Smith" is found in the current worksheet, get the cell address and offset from that cell location"
        Set OffsetCell = currentSheet.Range(FoundCell.Address).Offset(0, 5)

         'In Column "H" select the adjacent non-blank cells and copy into a range <line below where I define "FoundRange" is where I keep getting the "runtime error 424 object required error"
         Set FoundRange = Range(OffsetCell, OffsetCell.End(xlDown))

                 For Each cell In FoundRange.Cells
                    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                        currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Copy
                        masterSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        masterSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Format(CDate(Replace(Replace(currentSheet.Name, "Week of ", " "), ".", "/")), "mm/dd/yyyy")
                        masterSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1) = "James Bradford"
                        currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Copy
                        masterSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Copy
                        masterSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        currentSheet.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Copy
                        masterSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If
                Next


        End With

    End If
```

End Sub